# Write faster pdfs with tcpdf

Tags: php, pdf-generation, tcpdf

I generated pdfs with tcpdf using writeHTML. What I do, I write entirely html code and after that I generate pdfs with writeHTML.

My problem is that it's very slow. Generating 5 pages of data table (5 cols x 12 rows per page) takes about 10 seconds.

I followed almost all instructions from here: http://www.tcpdf.org/performances.php . 
I put

```
$pdf->setFontSubsetting(false) ;
```

Do you have other tips? Is it going to be more faster if I generate pdfs problematically?

Comment: I did my table using `ln`,`cell`,`write` but I gained a 2x performance reducing from 40 sec to 20 sec for 20 pages. I think it is too much.

Comment: if use cell, write, is possible to use `breaking table` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generating HTML, letting TCPDF parse that HTML and rejiggle it into Postscript instructions, then write this Postscript is of course going to be way slower than directly writing the Postscript to begin with. Use the regular `Ln`, `Cell`, `Write` etc. methods to directly generate the PDF if you want maximum performance. Yes, it's somewhat more complicated than writing HTML, but that's because they're different things. And the slow part is translating between those different things.

Comment: if use cell, write, is possible to use `breaking rows` ?